# Issue installing Pyrit on Kali

Tags: python, kali-linux

I am trying to install pyrit from GitHub on my Kali. The issue is that when I run the build which of setup.py, which is - `python setup.py build`, I get this error `Python.h not found`. This error is quite common and seems to have only one solution - `sudo apt-get install python-dev`. But when I run this command, I get an error - `python-dev has not installation candidate`. Please help.

Comment: There appear to be some possible solutions here (read whole thread).  https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?25203-Installing-Python-dev-fails

Comment: Didn't get the needed help @John.

Comment: Try:  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove then restart and try installing again.